# Getting error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, craftcms

So I've got an issue with element-api in php, which is a plugin for CRAFT cms, could someone help - what am I doing wrong here? I can't print time.json - always getting :

> {"error":{"code":0,"message":"Class name must be a valid object or a
> string"}}

here's the code:

```
<?php

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\controllers\TemplatesController;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use craft\web\View;
use craft\elements\User;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
    'tooltip-modal.json' => function() {
            
        $affiliateId = Craft::$app->request->getParam('entryId');
        $siteLanguage = Craft::$app->request->getParam('siteLanguage');

        $data = [
            'elementType' => Entry::class,
            'paginate' => false,
            'transformer' => function(Entry $affiliate) {
                $view = Craft::$app->getView();
                // $view->setTemplateMode($view::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
                return [
                    'affiliate' => $view->renderTemplate('modals/tooltipAffModal.twig', ['affiliate' => $affiliate])

                ];
            },
            'criteria' => ['id' => $affiliateId, 'site' => $siteLanguage]
        ];
        
        return $data;
    },
    'time.json' => function() {
        // $userId = Craft::$app->request->request->getParam('userId');

        $data = [
            'elementType' => User::class,
            'paginate' => false,
            'transformer' => function(User $user) {
                return [
                    'date' => $user->winHistory::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one()
                    

                ];
            },
            // 'criteria' => ['id' => $affiliateId, 'site' => $siteLanguage]

        ];
        return $data;
    }
    ]
];
```

Comment: which line throws that error please? Always give us the full info when reporting a problem.

Comment: @ADyson sorry about that,  this one - 
'date' => $user->winHistory::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one()